# Is duplicating a config file from vendor a must in Lumen?

Tags: package, config, lumen

I've installed a new package on Lumen and there is a config file in that `package(vendor/friskals/countries/config/country)`. Do I have to duplicate that file to the folder config in my project to use the value in that file?  I try not to copy it and there is no impact. So, I wonder whether it will have an impact in the future or not.
[folder config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bq1S.png)